# Flutter's sdk on Mac os

Tags: flutter, dart

I did the required steps when I want to check flutter...

[image: when I want to check flutter...]

But unfortunately  it does not work: i save it like ":wq! then clicked "ENTER""

[image]

Can u help me with setup for Mac Mojave?

Comment: **Bakhtovar Umarov**, is information about **ZSH** to use at _.zprofile_ help you?

Answer (score 0):

Your SH is **ZSH** default

then tour need to type not at *.bash_profile* but at **.zprofile**

your edit:
[image]

but this show:
[image]
**ZSH**

Comment: Thank you very much, now it shows me my version. ))

Comment: It turned from bush to ash since Mojave automatically